# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, string

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 and MySQL. I'm creating a form where I can Add the Employees. However, when I click the Add Button I got an error stating "Input string was not in a correct format."

This is the Screen shots:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
private void button_adduser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=timekeeping;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=admin;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand com = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "insert into users(fname, mname, lname, position, contactnumber, emailadd, birthday, username, password) values(@fname, @mname, @lname, @position, @contactnumber, @emailadd, @birthday, @username, @password)";
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@position", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@contactnumber", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@emailadd", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@birthday", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters["@fname"].Value = addfname.Text;
                command.Parameters["@mname"].Value = addmname.Text;
                command.Parameters["@lname"].Value = addlname.Text;
                command.Parameters["@position"].Value = addposition.Text;
                command.Parameters["@contactnumber"].Value = addcontact.Text;
                command.Parameters["@emailadd"].Value = addemail.Text;
                command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = addbday.Text;
                command.Parameters["@username"].Value = addusername.Text;
                command.Parameters["@password"].Value = addpassword.Text;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = addbday.Text;
```

addbday.Text is not in not a datetime field.

Even though you did declare it to be a datetime:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@birthday", SqlDbType.DateTime));
```

Rewrite the offending line to:

```
 command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(addbday.Text);
```

Comment: I already applied your suggestion to rewrite it to " command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(addbday.Text);" still have errors though.

Comment: @schadi: Are you still getting the exact same error? This answer seems correct.

Comment: @schadi, please don't say "I still get errors", paste the exact error message in a comment instead. Clairvoyance is a rare skill on SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

An example, you declared your "birthday" as datetime
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@birthday", SqlDbType.DateTime));

but, your value is being inserted as 
command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = addbday.Text; // which im not sure if you are in the right format or not.

That's why you have format error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at this line, since the parameter is declared as a datetime.  Make sure it is in an expected format.

```
command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = addbday.Text;
```

Comment: @schadi, please produce the exception again, then use the copy full exception to clipboard button and post the full exception and stack trace.